# How to convert array values to variables

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic-variables

I have value an array like this:

```
multi_arr = ["resi_spec","resi_desc"];
```

So each array value is considered as a variable and I want to store some value of these variables dynamically like this:

```
resi_spec = "good morning"
resi_desc = "good evening";
```

So that the array values are converted as variables. Is this possible?

I don't want use use obj[resi_spec] like this and i used array not variable if i just enter resi_spec means , i'll get good morning.

Comment: Where do you get the values that should fit in ?

Comment: This sounds like something you should be using an object for.

Comment: Where do you get the values `"good morning"` and `""good evening"`?

Comment: The current upvoted answers works. The gist is 1) you need a container object (be it `global` or `window`); 2) you can use variable in bracket notation.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an object to hold the values:

```js
var multi_arr = ["resi_spec","resi_desc"];
var resi = {};
multi_arr.forEach(function(val) { 
    resi[val] = "good morning"; 
});
```

Obviously you will want to set different values for each object attribute which you could accomplish with a helper function:

```js
var lookupHelper = function(key) {
    if (key == 'resi_spec') return 'good morning';
    if (key == 'resi_desc') return 'good evening';
};
var multi_arr = ["resi_spec","resi_desc"];
var resi = {};
multi_arr.forEach(function(val) { 
    resi[val] = lookupHelper(val); 
});
```

Comment: Good approach, although the `forEach` method is going to be quite useless if you want to have different values. However you could use another array for those…

Comment: To set different values, you would just implement a bit of additional code to look up the proper value. I've added an example to show how you would accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is having an object like bellow

```
multi_arr = ["resi_spec","resi_desc"];
var obj = {};
obj[multi_arr[0]] = "good morning";
obj[multi_arr[1]] = "good evening";
console.log(obj); //prints Object {resi_spec: "good morning", resi_desc: "good evening"})
```

you can access variables like bellow

```
console.log(obj["resi_spec"]); //prints "good morning";
console.log(obj["resi_desc"]); //prints "good evening";
```

Comment: Sorry This is not what i expected. just i enter alert(resi_spc); i want to get answer good morning. i won't  use object is it possible?

Comment: @SatheeshSivaNallathambi what do you want then ?

Answer (score 4):

You could also do the following.. Although not really recommended, since you will be creating global variables. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7jd25h3/)

```
var varNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
for(var i = 0; i < varNames.length; i++){
  window[varNames[i]] = i;
}
console.log(name1); // 0
console.log(name2); // 1
console.log(name3); // 2
```

Comment: This is basically almost the same as the object approach only that your object is the global object.

Comment: @Xufox but unlike other answers you can access them with their name directly (even not recommended)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so I misunderstood your question, so here is my **edited** response.

```
var multi_arr = ["resi_spec","resi_desc"];

var object = {};

object[multi_arr[0]] = "good morning";
object[multi_arr[1]] = "good evening";

console.log(object);
```

Comment: You’d be better off just deleting your answer and posting a new one, although now it’s probably too late.

Comment: There is little point reposting as other answers are now valid.